# ionic filepath plugin issue - resolveNativePath not working for android 13

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, path, permissions

Ionic filepath plugin - resolveNativePath not working for android 13
when choosing image from 'CHOOSE FROM GALLERY' it results as error

'Unable to resolve filesystem path.'
`

`this.fileChooser.open()
.then(uri => {
console.log('fileChooser URI: ' + uri);

```
    // uri = 'file://' + uri;
    // console.log('image path', uri)

    this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri)
      .then(fname => {

        console.log('filePath fname: ' + fname);
        let correctPath = uri.substr(0, uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        let currentName = fname.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        console.log(currentName);

        this.firstfilename = currentName;
        this.firstfilepath = uri;


        console.log(correctPath);
        console.log(uri);
        console.log(currentName);
        console.log(uri);

        console.log('Image URI: ' + uri);

        console.log(this.wp);



      }).catch(e => {
        console.log('filePath err', e);
      });




  }).catch(e => {
    console.log('fileChooser err', e);
  });``
```

Error: Unable to resolve filesystem path.